# A few problems im having with some c# windows forms code

Tags: c#, forms

I am trying to format a Textbox in C# to load Text into a message box that pops up after the user enters the text into a textbox on a form, and I'm getting some errors that i can't figure out how to resolve. The code i have so far is below

```
private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            InputClass.yourname = txtName.text;
        }

        txtName.Text = " "
    }
```

The first error I am getting is with the txtName.text; portion of the code, where i am receiving an error message that says " Error CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no accessible extension method 'text' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I am also getting another error message further down (it actually repeats itself twice is on the line txtName.Text = " " line, and the error message is "Error CS1519 Invalid token '=' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration"

I am stumped on these error messages and cant figure out how to resolve them. Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: Do you have a typo with `txtName.text`? The property name is `.Text` with an upper case T like in your last line of code (although you are missing a semicolon on that line tho).

Comment: Voting to close, you asked the day before and haven't responded to any of the comments offering you help: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69339094/a-few-errors-im-having-with-a-c-sharp-textboxs-and-invalid-tokens-and-object-d#comment122735610_69339094

Answer (score 1):

You need to have all your code inside a function in C#.

Also this is probably a better example of what you may be trying to do:

```
// This wasn't included in your example
public class SomeClass
{
    private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Show your messagebox
        MessageBox.Show(TextBox1.Text);
        // Do this instead
        TextBox1.Text = " ";
    }
    // You can't do this...
    // txtName.Text = " "
}
```

Your question isn't very clear but hopefully this helps.

Comment: I am wondering if the OP created a new C# file instead of modifying the generated code-behind file for the form.